# laravel wysiwyg editor - saving html to database

Tags: mysql, laravel, wysiwyg

i m writing a wysiwyg editor, and all the client side works perfectly, 
i am also **able to echo the data correctly on server side**, but **after saving** the post object, either all or most of it goes missing.

playing with strip_tags, mysql_real_...etc gives different results but never the *exact* html i had.

here s how i save the post object

```
foreach( Input::all() as $key=>$value ){
        $key != '_token' ? $post->$key = ($value) : 0;
        }
```

how do i solve this problem?

p.s. i have mysql db, of course

Answer (score 4):

all works! problem was DB related - after changing field type from varchar(255) to varchar(10000) or text(which is actually the right one for such data) everything works as planned.